# RapidApi / PAW app not opening on M1 Mac with MacOS Monterey 12.6.2

Tags: macos-monterey, rapidapi

Since upgrading my M1 Mac to macOS Monterey 12.6.2, RapidAPI app has stopped working.
It never opens up.

How to fix or debug this?

Tried it on another colleague's machine with macOS Monterey 12.6.1 and works fine for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got fixed by using an App Cleaner and reinstalling RapidAPI app.
Seems like 12.6.2 OS upgrade messed with access to some existing paths used by this app. App Cleaner deleted all those files too and fresh installation launched successfully.

Re-installation after regular deleting of the app from /Applications did not work as any new installation kept referencing older paths.